# Storing php sessions in redis as json, read the session

Tags: php, json, node.js, session

I'm storing my php sessions in redis as json string to share them with node.js like it is done here:

http://simplapi.wordpress.com/2012/04/13/php-and-node-js-session-share-redi/

What I don't like is that these functions store the sessions on disk and in redis. I just want them in redis. As json.

I thought it would be easy to change this and I guess it is but I don't know how.

I can't use session_encode(); on a specific variable. Do i need to serialize unserialze? What format do I have to return for the read function?

```
public function read($id) {

    $id = $this->_prefix . $id;

    try {

        $r = $this->__rc
            ->multi()
            ->get($id)
            ->expire($id, $this->ttl)
            ->exec();

    } catch (\RedisException $e) { return false; }


    $tmp      = $_SESSION;
    $_SESSION = json_decode( $r[0], true );

    if( isset( $_SESSION ) && ! empty( $_SESSION ) && $_SESSION != null ){

        $new_data = session_encode();
        $_SESSION = $tmp;
        return $new_data;

    } 

    else{ 

        return ''; 

    }

}

public function write($id, $data) {

    $tmp = $_SESSION;
    session_decode($data);
    $new_data = $_SESSION;
    $_SESSION = $tmp;

    $id = $this->_prefix . $id;

    try{

        $this->__rc
            ->multi()
            ->set( $id, json_encode($new_data) )
            ->expire($id, $this->ttl)
            ->exec();

    } catch (\RedisException $e) { return false; }

    return true;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to save the session only in Redis and not on disk you need to change the settings for storing session in you php.ini like session_save path.